# Nuance between いか and イカ?

Tags: meaning, nuances, animals

Both mean squid but is there any difference between the use of hiragana or katakana?

Answer (score 1):

イカ is used more frequently.
いか is Japanese style, cute and childish.
イカ is standard and scientific.

Answer (score 0):

I heard somewhere that animals can be written in katakana to make they seem more cute or playful.

Examples:
鴨: ooh, so foreign, fancy
かも: standard
カモ: playful, cute, childish, advertising appeal

Comment: Katakana animal names are standard in scientific contexts